# Why does distribution profile say its enabled for push when the app id does not have push configured?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

My app id does not have push configured:
[image]

But the distribution profile (ad-hoc) says push is enabled:
[image]

If I delete the profile and create a new one, it still says push is enabled. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's shown in Distribution Profile simply pulls all the "Application Services" you've "included" into your AppId <- said that you'll use while creating it. However, services like Push Notifications won't work until you create certificates and enable that functionality in the app. Worst thing that might happen until you set everything up is getting log in Xcode saying something like "Provisioning Profile includes Push Notifications entitlement but application is not configured..."